# Rails 3, ActiveAdmin custom filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have 3 associated models:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_models
end

class CarModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :production_years
  belongs_to :brand
end

class ProductionYear < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car_model
end
```

So, how i can make custom filter in ActiveAdmin production_year section, if i want make filtering by Brand? Default filters there: car_model select and year value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
ActiveAdmin.register ProductionYear do
  filter :brand, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => proc { Brand.all }
end
```

EDIT oops I didn't notice the complexity of your association, I think if you add this to your ProductionYear class things should work better:

```
class ProductionYear < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :car_model
   has_one :brand, :through => :car_model
end
```

Comment: Yes, this cause error "Undefined methon 'brand_eq'" for #<MetaSearch::Searches::ProductionYear:...>

Comment: Ahhh the problem is in the model associations, I appended my answer to reflect this

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it really works!
But maybe you can help next to. If i add one more child model for ProductionYear, how to make double 'through' association?

Comment: Got dropdown with values but when i filter with this , iam getting empty list