# ActiveAdmin, polymorphic associations, and custom filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, polymorphic-associations, activeadmin

Rails 3.1, ActiveAdmin 0.3.4.

My question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804280/rails-3-activeadmin-custom-filter) but different enough in terms of data modeling that I think it warrants its own response. Models:

```
class CheckoutRequest < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :request_common_data, :as => :requestable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class RequestCommonData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :requestable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

The `RequestCommonData` model has a `completed` field (boolean) that I'd like to be able to filter in ActiveAdmin's `CheckoutRequest` index page. I've tried a few different approaches to no avail, including the following:

```
filter :completed, :collection => proc { CheckoutRequest.all.map { |cr| cr.request_common_data.completed }.uniq }
```

which results in no filter being displayed. Adding `:as => :select` to the line, as follows:

```
filter :completed, :as => :select, :collection => proc { CheckoutRequest.all.map { |cr| cr.request_common_data.completed }.uniq }
```

results in the following MetaSearch error message:

```
undefined method `completed_eq' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::CheckoutRequest:0x007fa4d8faa558>
```

That same proc returns `[true, false]` in the console.

Any suggestions would be quite welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the meta_search gem page you can see that for boolean values the 'Wheres' are:

- is_true - Is true. Useful for a checkbox like “only show admin users”.
- is_false - The complement of is_true.

so what you need is to change the generate input name from 'completed_eq' to be 'completed_is_true' or 'completed_is_false'.

The only way I have found this possible to do is with Javascript, since by looking at the Active Admin code, the 'Wheres' are hardcoded for each data type.

I would usually have a line like this in my activeadmin.js file (using jQuery)

```
$('#q_completed_eq').attr('name', 'q[completed_is_true]');
```

or

```
$('#q_completed_eq').attr('name', 'q[completed_is_false]');
```

Terrible and ugly hack but have found no other solution myself.

Be careful to enable this only in the pages you want.

--- NEW FOR VERSION 0.4.2 and newer ---

Now Active Admin uses separate modules for each :as => ... option in the filters.
So for example you can place the code below inside an initializer file

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Inputs
    class FilterCustomBooleanInput < ::Formtastic::Inputs::SelectInput
      include FilterBase

      def input_name
        "#{@method}_is_true"
      end

      def input_options
        super.merge(:include_blank => I18n.t('active_admin.any'))
      end

      def method
        super.to_s.sub(/_id$/,'').to_sym
      end

      def extra_input_html_options
        {}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and the use

```
:as => :custom_boolean
```

where you specify your filter.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll have a look and see if this works for me. If it does, I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: So in newer code, the `ActiveAdmin::Inputs:: FilterCustomBooleanInput` class would be located in repo at: `app/admin/filter_custom_boolean_input.rb`? I'm going to test this approach with `activeadmin` at version `1.4.3`